# Discord button only works once discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I have posted a button but it only works once
[image]
but after that when I use it again

[image]

**Also**

How can I reply to message if I use `deferUpdate` it shows

**Code**

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity('people and managing the server', {
    type: 'WATCHING',
  });

  const channel = client.channels.cache.get('894171605608042496');

  const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId('openTicket')
      .setLabel('Create ticket')
      .setEmoji('')
      .setStyle('SECONDARY')
  );

  channel
    .send({
      embeds: [
        {
          title: 'SGAS Tickets',
          color: '#388e3c',
          description: 'To create a ticket react with ',
        },
      ],
      components: [row],
    })
    .then(() => {
      const filter = () => {
        return true;
      };

      const collector = channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
        filter,
        time: 15 * 1000,
      });
      collector.on('collect', (i) => {
        i.deferUpdate().then(() => {
          Ticket.count({}, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              const ticketNumber = result + 1;
              const ticketString = convertNumber(ticketNumber);
              const ticket = new Ticket({
                tickedId: ticketString,
              });
              ticket.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                } else {
                  const myguild = client.guilds.cache.get('887277806386565150');
                  if (!myguild) {
                    console.log('guild not found');
                    return;
                  }
                  const category = myguild.channels.cache.find(
                    (c) =>
                      c.id === '887277807279947826' &&
                      c.type == 'GUILD_CATEGORY'
                  );
                  if (!category) {
                    console.log('category not found');
                    return;
                  }
                  myguild.channels
                    .create(`Ticket#${ticketString}`, {
                      type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
                    })
                    .then(async (myc) => {
                      myc.setParent(category).then(() => {
                        myc.send(
                          `Hello <@${i.user.id}>, your question will be solved here shortly`
                        );
                        i.reply({
                          content: `Go to <#${myc.id}>, for your question`,
                          ephemeral: true,
                        });
                      });
                    });
                }
              });
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: You shared a private key with us - I strongly recommend you changing your keys now

Comment: btw, that wasn't private key that was channel id

Comment: Apologies, I read that and it seemed that it was a private key. I am not particularly an expert here, but isn't onReady only ran once when the bot is connected?

Comment: I mean when I click again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a component collector - which expires in 15 seconds, as seen in your code. That means after 15 seconds your bot stops listening for button clicks. My recommendation is to use the `interactionCreate` event to listen for that button: see docs https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ButtonInteraction

Example:

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
 if(!interaction.isButton()) return;
 if(interaction.customId === "openTicket") {
  // your ticket code here
 }
});
```